# CakePhp 3.0 - Authorization with some free action

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I'm totally new to the CakePhp framework, so I'm doing the basic tutorial. So far so good, I built the scaffolding for my models, authentication works fine, but I't a little excessive: I would like to allow one action ('index' for example) to be allowed even for non-authenticated users.

I suspect it must have something with "BeforeFilter()", but any solution I tried hasn't worked - probably because they'for CPHP 2.0, and/or I'm dumb
.

The code is here, though it's not particuolarily interesting since it's the one generated by the scaffolding mechanism.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Frutta Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\FruttaTable $Frutta
 */
class FruttaController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('frutta', $this->paginate($this->Frutta));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['frutta']);
    }

//cut..
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
function beforeFilter() {
     parent::beforeFilter();
     $this->Auth->allow('index'); //allow index without authentication 
}
```

Reference : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public